# how to repeatedly ask the user to input a sentence and it should stop if the user types END also should count the no. of words,vowels and non vowels

Tags: java, string

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class exampaper
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count=0;
        int count1=1;
        int count2=0;
    //  boolean t =false;

        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence");
        String s1=scan.nextLine();

        while(!s1.equals("END"))
        {

            System.out.println(s1);
            s1=scan.nextLine();

            if(s1.equals("END"))
            {
            System.out.println("END");
            }


        }

        for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
        {

            if(s1.charAt(i)==' ')
            {
                count1++;
            }
            else if(s1.charAt(i)=='a'||s1.charAt(i)=='A')
            {
                count++;
            }
            else if(s1.charAt(i)=='e'||s1.charAt(i)=='E')
            {
                count++;
            }
            else if(s1.charAt(i)=='i'||s1.charAt(i)=='I')
            {
                count++;
            }
            else if(s1.charAt(i)=='o'||s1.charAt(i)=='O')
            {
                count++;
            }
            else if(s1.charAt(i)=='u'||s1.charAt(i)=='U')
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                count2++;
            }



        }
    System.out.println("Number of vowels: " +count);
    System.out.println("Number of words: " +count1 );
    System.out.println("Number of non-vowels: " +count2);
    }

}
```

i am not able to count the no. of vowels,words and non vowels when i have the while loop for the repeatedly asking the question to Please type a sentence. I dont know whats wrong with it . Can someone give me a suggestion please.Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write a programme that determines the number of words,vowels,non-vowels and programme should keep asking please enter sentence until user enters STOP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916778/write-a-programme-that-determines-the-number-of-words-vowels-non-vowels-and-prog)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: You want to structure your code like the following pseudo code:

```
public class ExamPaperAnswerFromStackOverflow {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        initializations-here

        while( true ) {
            System.out.println("Your prompt here");
            s1 = scan.nextLine();
            if ( !s1.equals("your-terminator-here") ) {
                break;
            }

            for-each-character {
                // code-to-count-vowels-constants-words-here
            }
        }

        print-summary-here
    }
}
```

The "infinite loop" will prompt the user for a string, each time through the loop, but `break` out of the loop when `"your-terminator-here"` is received.

Comment: while what is true ?

Comment: and is that a for loop for each character

Comment: Since this is clearly homework (or self-study), as you will learn more from doing than just having the answer handed to you, I answered in a combination of Java and pseudo code.  You already have a for loop which goes through each character, but just didn't have it nested inside the an outer loop for each line the user enters.  As for "while what is true": `while (true) { ... }` is an infinite loop.  It loops while the expression in parenthesis evaluates to `true`.  Since the expression in parenthesis is the literal constant `true`, it loops forever ... or rather, until there is a `break;`.